# How to hide restore option in app icon system menu wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF and I want to keep the main window in maximized window state. If I click on the app icon the system menu gives 'Restore' option in order to change the window state from Maximized to normal. I want stop changing the window state to Normal state. It would be really helpful if anyone can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your `<Window>` simply set the Property `ResizeMode` to `NoResize`.

Example

```
<Window 
    ...ALL THE STUFF THAT'S ALREADY HERE...
    ResizeMode="NoResize"/>
```

If you still want to allow minimization, chose `"CanMinimize"` instead to `"NoResize"`.

Presumably you already have `WindowState="Maximized"` which will load the Window as Maximized.

Comment: Yeah but i want the minimized option as well.

Comment: Revised. You can used `"CanMinimize"`

Comment: Yeah but it didn't help. Because once i click on the system menu on app icon there is restore option. The problem is that changes the window state to normal state. Thank you.

Comment: It shouldn't be active/clickable, even if it's there. Are you sure you can actually click on it?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample? This *should* work. I've tested in my own app and "Restore" is disabled.

Comment: <Window>ShowSystemMenuOnRightClick="False"  WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" ResizeMode="CanMinimize"  WindowState="Maximized"</Window>

Comment: That's not proper XAML? If you're setting properties between the opening and closing tags, you should be writing it like `<Window><Window.ResizeMode>CanMinimize</Window.ResizeMode></Window>`.

Comment: Thank you but still have the same problem.